# When installing a new version, inno setup will put the uninstaller files in the old version's folder

Tags: inno-setup

I have an app installed at `C:\Program Files\MyApp`

The folder structure:

```
MyApp\
       Version1\
                Version1\
                          bin\
                unins000.dat
                unins000.exe
                unins000\
```

Now I have a new version (Version2) and I have a function `DeleteOldNTSBDirAndShortcuts()` in `function SetProgramFileLocation()` in my iss script. It will delete the whole folder of Version1 and remove its shortcut on the desktop.

It works fine on 64bit PC, however on a 32bit PC, the iss script will create a Version1 folder and put all the uninstallers in it. So the structure now is:

```
MyApp\
         Version2\
                   Version2\
                            bin\
         Version1
                  unins000.dat
                  unins000.exe
                  unins000\
```

Since the `AppID` is same, it looks like the system is still holding the old value (Version1) and use it to create the uninstallers.

Comment: Both those examples have the uninstall data in the same location. It just looks like you had `DefaultDirName` set to `{pf}\MyApp\Version1` and then wrote to `{app}\Version1\`. Can you include the relevant bits of your script (`[Setup]` and `[Files]`) so we can do better than guessing?

Comment: Oh, and this is the reason why version directories are normally frowned upon unless (and only if) multiple versions can coexist. If it's only ever valid to have one instance, then they should not go into versioned folders and inp place upgrades done.